# Java , The equals() Method

Tags: java, equals

i have this code in my main, why this code returns true?
equals() method was automatically written by NetBeans 7.3.1.

```
Movimento md = new Movimento(3, 1, 2014, 100, "Debito", 'D');

Movimento mc = new Movimento(3 , 1 , 2014, 100 , "Credito", 'C');

System.out.println(mc.equals(md));
```

this is the equals code ...

```
public boolean equals(Movimento obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (this.dia != obj.dia) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.mes != obj.mes) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.ano != obj.ano) {
        return false;
    }
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.valor) != Double.doubleToLongBits(obj.valor)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.descricao, obj.descricao)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.tipo != obj.tipo) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Post the `equals` method implementation as well...

Comment: Show your `equals` method then, we're not magicians.

Comment: You should probably show us equals method:)

Comment: Did you generate the `equals` method _then_ add the last two attributes to your `Movimento` class?

Comment: @user3097580 show the fields declaration also too.. and constructor!

Comment: ok, i found the problem , thanks for all answers , it was a problem in the constructor :D

Comment: @user3097580 Note that you're **not** overriding the `equals` method herited from the object class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result of `equals` method depends very much on its implementation.

Method `equals` of `Object`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

This means, that `equals` will return `true`, only if the two variables holds the references (therefore references to the same object).

If it returns `false`, this must by caused by overriding the original method.

I don't know, where is the bug, because I don't see your `equals` method, but I can give you an example, how to write one:

```
public class MyClass {

    private int integer;

    private String string;

    private char character;

    public MyClass(int integer, String string, char character) {
        this.integer = integer;
        this.string = string;
        this.character = character;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj == this)
            return true;

        if (!(obj instanceof MyClass))
            return false;

        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) obj;

        if (integer == myClass.integer && string.equals(myClass.string) && character == myClass.character)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

I hope this helps you to find out mistake...

Answer (score 0):

`Movimento` class `equals` method is NOT comparing all the attributes to check the equality of its objects.